# How can I detect when my moving ball hits non-moving brick?

Tags: collision-detection, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have been stuck on this for awhile now. I want to produce the sound of a bouncing ball when my ball falls onto the brick, so obviously I don't want the ball to go through the brick. However I want the brick to be completely static. How can I detect when the ball bounces on the brick without moving the brick? Currently I was playing around and got stumped. At my current settings, the sound is produced like I want, however since it is set to  "is Trigger" the ball just passes through the brick, which I don't want it to do. I want it to bounce on the brick without affecting the brick's position at all (static). Please help:

[image: Inspector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the `Is Trigger` bool on the collider.
Then add a custom script to the ball which overrides [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html). Follow the link for sample code.

I hope that helps!